# What is the difference between the methods PutExtra and PutExtras in Android?

Tags: java, android

What is the difference between `PutExtra()` method and `PutExtras()` method in `Android`?

Comment: check it here
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtras(android.content.Intent)
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String, android.os.Bundle)

Answer (score 3):

Both methods are Intent by help of

`PutExtra()`  - we can store any primitive data type directly with (key,value) pair.

And `PutExtras()` - hold object of `Bundle` class object .
`Bundle` class provide us method of specific primitive data type methods to store data in it.

and put Bundle object in `PutExtras()` method without  key value pair.

Answer (score 0):

putExtra contains a key-value pair

putExtras contains a bundle which is a map(contains multiple key-value pairs)